# Simply Google's copy

Tags: spring, search-engine

I would like to create simply search engine like Google or Bing. What does Google or Bing take a data from? What can I take data from?

I am going to create it in Spring framework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! FYI, search engines use crawlers. But this question is too broad, I advise you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about framework

but you need few things

1. All active domains list (check this https://whoisdatacenter.com/
2. you need a static IP and tell websites about use agent name --user-agent mybot
3. you must be very good with curl / sed/ awk/ grep
4. example I am using my bot and when I do nmap / nslookup / fetching websites data in index in my database, I simply tell all websites that who am i..
5. dont use user-agent like Google/Yahoo , you will be blocked by many servers

PS: I am also a new guy... but somehow I manage to do my work by above steps.

there are 184-210 million active domains. you need a powerful server. I made on bash